# how to read/assign the elements of a pointer that points to an array of structures in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, struct, core-audio

In iOS core audio there is the API [AudioFileWritePackets](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/AudioFileConvertRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/AudioFileWritePackets) that has a `inPacketDescriptions` parameter defined as
'A pointer to an array of packet descriptions for the audio data.'

and it looks like this in the method signature:
`const AudioStreamPacketDescription *inPacketDescriptions,`

now the struct AudioStreamPacketDescription is defined as follows:

```
struct  AudioStreamPacketDescription
{
    SInt64  mStartOffset;
    UInt32  mVariableFramesInPacket;
    UInt32  mDataByteSize;
};
typedef struct AudioStreamPacketDescription AudioStreamPacketDescription;
```

I would like to know how to create and populate such a 'pointer to an array of structs', or even once given the variable, how to read it. Using the [speakHere](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/AudioFileConvertRef/Reference/reference.html) example from apple I put a breakpoint where I receive the variable and tried to dump all its contents to the log.. this is an example of an attempt:

```
void AQRecorder::printPacketDescriptionContents(const AudioStreamPacketDescription * inPacketDescriptions, UInt32 inNumberPackets)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < inNumberPackets; ++i)
    {
        NSLog(@"\n----------------\n");
        NSLog(@"this is packetDescriptionArray[%d].mStartOffset: %lld", i, (*inPacketDescriptions).mStartOffset);
        NSLog(@"this is packetDescriptionArray[%d].mVariableFramesInPacket: %lu", i, (*inPacketDescriptions).mVariableFramesInPacket);
        NSLog(@"this is packetDescriptionArray[%d].mDataByteSize: %lu", i, (*inPacketDescriptions).mDataByteSize);
        NSLog(@"\n----------------\n");   

    }        
}
```

any ideas?

**Update:** here is a sample log of me trying to mess around with it.. maybe it can help in the answer (notice at the bottom it keeps on appearing null.. it doesn't make sense that the whole thing is just a pack of zeroes since it's a variable returned by a callback that *should* be properly populated, also notice that it informs me about the number of packets I got back..).. also if i run the code with `((const AudioStreamPacketDescription *)(inPacketDescriptions +i))->mDataByteSize)` i get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error

```
(lldb) po **(inPacketDescriptions)
error: indirection requires pointer operand ('const AudioStreamPacketDescription' invalid)
error: 1 errors parsing expression
(lldb) po *(inPacketDescriptions)
(AudioStreamPacketDescription) $1 = [no Objective-C description available]
(lldb) po *(inPacketDescriptions).mStartOffset
error: member reference type 'const AudioStreamPacketDescription *' is a pointer; maybe you meant to use '->'?
error: indirection requires pointer operand ('SInt64' (aka 'long long') invalid)
error: 2 errors parsing expression
(lldb) po (*inPacketDescriptions).mStartOffset
(SInt64) $2 = 0 <nil>

(lldb) po (const AudioStreamPacketDescription *)(inPacketDescriptions +1)
(const class AudioStreamPacketDescription *) $3 = 0x00000010 [no Objective-C description available]
(lldb) po (const AudioStreamPacketDescription *)(inPacketDescriptions +1)->mStartOffset
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: Attempted to dereference an invalid pointer..
The process has been returned to the state before execution.
(lldb) po ((const AudioStreamPacketDescription *)(inPacketDescriptions +1))->mStartOffset
(SInt64) $5 = 0 <nil>
(lldb) po ((const AudioStreamPacketDescription *)(inPacketDescriptions +1))->mDataByteSize
(UInt32) $6 = 0 <nil>
(lldb) po ((const AudioStreamPacketDescription *)(inPacketDescriptions +100))->mDataByteSize
(UInt32) $7 = 0 <nil>
(lldb) po ((const AudioStreamPacketDescription *)(inPacketDescriptions +500))->mDataByteSize
(UInt32) $8 = 0 <nil>

(lldb) po inPacketDescriptions[0].mStartOffset
error: parent failed to evaluate: parent is NULL
(lldb)
```

also here is what it looks like in the XCode inspector:[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't remember an instance where this specific struct is ever populated by you, the client. You will need to create *storage* for these structs which you then pass across multiple calls in order to successfully deal with reading and writing audio data. Several non-PCM formats will need this information, depending on how the audio data has been stored.

> I would like to know how to create and populate such a 'pointer to an array of structs', or even once given the variable, how to read it.

Well, there are a handful of APIs in AudioFile I/O and AudioConvertor interfaces which use this structure. Basically, you don't populate this type yourself. The basic flow goes like this:

```
// this is not for PCM audio data
//
// we'll read up to 8 packets at a time:
const size_t MaxPacketsToRead(8);

// allocate MaxPacketsToRead ASPDs on the stack:
AudioStreamPacketDescription aspds[MaxPacketsToRead];

// audio file read function:
AudioFileID inAudioFile = ...;
Boolean inUseCache = ...;
UInt32 outNumBytes = ...;
AudioStreamPacketDescription* outPacketDescriptions(aspds);
SInt64 inStartingPacket = ...;
UInt32 ioNumPackets = MaxPacketsToRead; // << you may not get all the packets
                                        // you request, but this sets the
                                        // upper limit.
void* outBuffer = ...;


OSStatus result(AudioFileReadPackets(inAudioFile,
                                     inUseCache,
                                     &outNumBytes,
                                     outPacketDescriptions,
                                     inStartingPacket,
                                     &ioNumPackets,
                                     outBuffer
));

if (noErr != result) {
  ...uh-oh...
}

// *now* we know that we have ioNumPackets worth of valid ASPDs,
// populated by the reader. and we have the associated audio data
// in other parameters.
// we can now safely pass all this information off to a function which 
// reads the ASPDs, such as AudioFileWritePackets.
```

*(knowing the OP's problem in some more detail)* In many cases, you can avoid all this complexity and simply create an `ExtAudioFile` representation, and the specify `kExtAudioFileProperty_ClientDataFormat` for your destination sample format -- then the ExtAudioFile APIs will create an internal convertor on your behalf which will convert the input of an audio file of an arbitrary type to some specified PCM representation which you can use for the playback sample data. Implementing all this at this level is actually quite complex if you want to support many file formats. ExtAudioFile makes converting the sample data very easy -- if that is an option and if it plays nicely with your streaming scenario.

As far as the logging, well you're attempting to print the fields of a NULL structure, from the looks of it.

Comment: you are right about the null structure part.. it turns out the file i was reading from was PCM (uncompressed).. which naturally don't have packet descriptions..The reason why i'm playing with the content of the packet descriptions myself is that i'm reading these packets descriptions from an audio file (using CMSampleBufferGetAudioStreamPacketDescriptionsPtr) and packaging this information in a custom made packet I created to send data over bluetooth.. once I receive it on the client side.. i must extract the data out of the packet I sent it and package it in a proper ..

Comment: @www.fossfactory.org *The reason why i'm playing with the content of the packet descriptions…* ah, cool. that makes sense in that scenario, in the event you are unable to simply transfer the audio file you stream as raw data and read it from your reader (which could also be complex to implement with some formats due to distribution of the data -- that is, it could be a relatively long time before you have enough information before you could begin playback in some cases).

Comment: .. AudioStreamPacketDescription format, which i will in turn feed it over to AudioFileWritePackets.. so that's the plan. On a related note.. I was going some of my other audio experiments and I noticed that in one case I was reading audio data via *AudioFileReadPackets* and sending it over the network *without* the audioPacketDescriptions.. even though it's a VBR file (ie .mp3).. and on the receiving side i get the packets and parse it via AudioFileStreamParseBytes.. which in turn recreates the packetDescriptions (using its AudioFileStream_PacketsProc callback).. any idea why that happens?

Comment: @www.fossfactory.org `AudioFileStreamParseBytes` is designed to work with a file as it is stored on disk. i am surprised it appeared to work following a decode process. *(shrugs)* the idea is that you can stream file input into it as the data becomes available -- then it notifies you when it has enough data to make sense of the file (stating the obvious).

Comment: @justin I have a similar problem, `const size_t MaxPacketsToRead(8);` this doesn't work for me though, I am trying `AudioStreamPacketDescription tempDesc[packetsFilledDesc];` where `packetsFilledDesc` is calculated during runtime after a for loop. however since it is a struct array it returns null. If I do `AudioStreamPacketDescription tempDesc[24];` it works but I can't use constants. How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Declare an array of `AudioStreamPacketDescription`:

```
AudioStreamPacketDescription descriptions[10];

/* Populate 'descriptions' */
descriptions[0].mVariableFramesInPacket = 4; /* For example. */
```

then pass it to the function:

```
/* 'a' is an instance of AQRecorder. */
a.printPacketDescriptionContents(descriptions, 10);
```

when an array is passed to a function it decays to a pointer (to the first element of the array).

The example `printPacketDescriptionContents()` is only accessing the first element of the array `inNumberPackets` times: you need to access each element:

```
NSLog(@"this is packetDescriptionArray[%d].mStartOffset: %lld",
      i,
      inPacketDescriptions[i].mStartOffset);
```

Comment: I tried exactly that before (ie  inPacketDescriptions[i].mStartOffset).. and the error is: parent failed to evaluate: parent is NULL

Comment: @www.fossfactory.org, not sure what the problem is. Check this small demo http://ideone.com/UGRhi.

Comment: the code you linked to is just a custom made data structure you created (I believe).. it does not necessarily conform to the one in Core Audio that I'm dealing with unfortunately, nor does it behave the same way..

Comment: @www.fossfactory.org, it contains a guess at the data types yes, but gives an example of a working program that declares, populates and accesses an array of `struct`.